# Building binutils with debugging mode

Tags: c, mingw, gnu, binutils

I'm trying to build binutils 2.21 source code with debugging on. My main aim is to debug objdump actually. But in order to build it I think I have to build whole package.

Unfortunately there is no debugging option on the configure file. I tried adding -g and -ggdb to CFLAGS before I configure it. However the error was:

```
Configuring in ./intl
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
configure: error: `CFLAGS' has changed since the previous run:
configure:   former value:  `-g -O2 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS'
configure:   current value: `-g -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS'
configure: error: in `/c/binutils-2.21/intl':
configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm ./config.cache' and start over

make[1]: *** [configure-intl] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/binutils-2.21'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried "make clean" and "make distclean" but I'm receiving the same error. Actually according to former CFLAGS it had -g option on before but when I try to open objdump.exe in gdb it says

```
    Reading symbols from c:\binutils-2.21\binutils/objdump.exe...
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I've tried a lot. As I said -g tag was on to gcc. However makefile saves all debugging enabled binaries to binutils.libs\ directory. So when I run binutils.libs\objdump.exe under gdb it was fine. Thanks for your answer though.